# apply margin or padding to an absolute element

Tags: html, css

I have a absolute wrapper and absolute div, they have to be responsive, so I set them 100% width. How to set margin to the left and right?

```
.card{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px !important;
}

#card1{
    background:black;
    top:0;
    color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rrapj20o/6/

Comment: OT: are you supporting Fx 3.6 (and Saf 4 / Android 2.1)? Or you can safely stick to unprefixed border-radius property. Source: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius (click "Show all"). Autoprefixer is a great tool if you don't want to cope with adding (and more important - and seldomly done - removing) prefixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce your width by twice the margin you need on either side

```
width:95%;
margin: 0 2.5%;
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yqcgtjLd/

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple like the below. Before that you have to know where we have to mention `position:absolute`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rrapj20o/7/

Comment: huh? what did u change? I'm talking about margin at the sides.

Comment: You mentioned padding:10px along with 100% for #wrap. So it will take 100% + 20px size in width. One more thing, i put *{margin:0; padding:0}. So all the html tags will get margin:0 and padding:0. Otherwise, each tag will get default margin and padding value. If my answer is useful, click up arrow